# Detect Phone Number & Link in xamarin.Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

assume we have the following text :

> Contact us on 015546889 or email@hotmail.com

How I can display the above text in same label in xamarin.forms and handle click on email by send email and handle phone call by click on the number.

I can use the the following code to make clickable label

```
Label label = new Label;
     label.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
    {
         Command = new Command(() => {
           //do some function here
        })
   });
```

How to hyperlink same as messaging app or Whatsapp application

Comment: The native controls have capabilities to do this. Look into the UITextView for example for iOS. You will have to implement it through a custom renderer or similar. There is currently no support from Xamarin.Forms directly.

Comment: I have not tried it but there is a plugin xam.plugins.messaging. Let me know if it worked for you I might use it too later :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of search i found the perfect solution Here :
https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/tag/xamarin-hyperlink-label/

Hope this will help others :)

Comment: This is the perfect answer, works on both Android/iOS with xamarin.forms 4

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Label element in Forms9Patch.  It has a HtmlText property that allows simple markup.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace Forms9PatchDemo
{
    public class LabelLink : ContentPage
    {
        public LabelLink()
        {
            var label = new Forms9Patch.Label
            {
                HtmlText = "Contact us on <a id=\"phone\" href=\"tel:+353015546889\">015546889</a> or <a id=\"email\" href=\"mailto:email@hotmail.com\">email@hotmail.com</a>"
            };
            label.ActionTagTapped += (object sender, Forms9Patch.ActionTagEventArgs e) =>
            {
                var id = e.Id;
                var href = e.Href;
                var uri = new Uri(e.Href);
                Device.OpenUri(uri);
            };
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Forms9Patch.Label.HtmlText <a> example" },
                    new BoxView { BackgroundColor = Color.Black, HeightRequest = 1 },
                    label
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above example won't work on iOS emulators because the `tel:` and `mailto:` schemes are not supported.  It does work on actual iOS devices.

Comment: UnLicensed COPY !!

Comment: Forms9Patch is now MIT Licensed open source.  No license needed.

Answer (score 0):

Same response as AAHN, https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/tag/xamarin-hyperlink-label/
But i dont have enoguh reputation to comment his answer.

Just an improvement in the android part, instead of overriding OnElementChanged, override CreateNativeControl so you add the mask there, that makes easier to get the styles of the xamarin.forms part correct because you are not overriding them.

```
    public class HyperLinkLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    private Context _context;
    public HyperLinkLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override TextView CreateNativeControl()
    {
        var view = base.CreateNativeControl();
        view.AutoLinkMask = MatchOptions.All;
        return view;
    }
}
```